# How do I find values similar but not identical to others?

Tags: r

I'm trying to bind values from one table with an index similar to another table. My tables look like this:

```
V1  V2  
1   1.2352
2   3.2345
3   2.2132
4   3.3344
```

The other table looks like this

```
V1  V2
1A  1.9494
1B  1.5092
1C  1.3242
2A  1.3833
2B  2.5223
etc...
```

I'm trying to get a table like this

```
V1  V2       V3 (value from table 1)
1A  1.9494   1.2352
1B  1.5092   1.2352
1C  1.3242   1.2352
2A  1.3833   3.2345
2B  2.5223   3.2345
```

Then, I have to iterate through a bunch of tables that go up to 1A1A1,

so in the end it'll look like this:

```
V1      V2     V3     V4    V5    
1A1A1   1A1A   1A1    1A    1
1A1A2   1A1A   1A1    1A    1
1A1B1   1A1B   1A1    1A    1
 etc....
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Split the names with `strsplit` and do a merge.

Comment: I don't understand your last data.frame -- can you re-explain it in other words?

Comment: basically, 1 is the value in dataframe1[1,V2], 1A is the value in  dataframe2[1,V2], so it's like a tree going down to the leaves, which are 1A1A1, 2A1A1, 2A2B3, 5B3A2, etc, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you to the third table above--the one you say you're trying to get to. Even with your clarifying comment I don't understand what the last table is.

```
# create data frames
df1 <- cbind(1:4,
             rnorm(4, mean = 2)
             )
df2 <- cbind(c('1A', '1B', '1C', '2A', '2B'),
             rnorm(5, mean = 2)
             )

# create a column in the second data frame to match on
df2 <- cbind(df2,
             data.frame(substr(df2[ , 1], start = 1, stop = 1))
             )
names(df2) <- c('V1', 'V2', 'V3')

# merge the two data frames by the key they have in common
merge(df2,
      df1,
      by.x = 'V3',
      by.y = 'V1'
      )
```

You can drop columns or reorganize them however you'd like at this point.